# CloudFare without Captcha

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I am trying to go to a website, namely, fiverr.com

However, Cloudfare blocks me and doesn't give me any chance to go past through the page.

There is NO CAPTCHA for me to see and type.

Any issues?[image]

EDIT: I am also trying to figure things out. I only have this problem when I am on a certain internet provider. I switched to another and the CAPTCHA worked. My problem is if I am human, how do I pass the test when the CAPTCHA doesn't show up?

Comment: Do you allow script?

Comment: What do you mean? I've only had this problem today. I've always seen the captcha... but today, almost half of all the sites I visit had this page without a CAPTCHA image.

Comment: Roya means Javascript. But maybe CloudFlare has changed something.

Comment: Hitting it from a Tor exit with Firefox, I got and passed a CAPTCHA, and got into the site. Hitting it with Tor browser, I had to pass a CAPTCHA, plus copy and paste a long string of characters. But it kept restarting, and didn't let me in, with no overt error message. But I never got the screen that OP shows with no CAPTCHA.

Comment: Perhaps a fresh Tor browser install would help. CloudFlare may have flagged OP's browser.

Comment: Select new identity from the tor button and keep trying.  You need a tor exit that hasn't been flagged by cloudflare yet.

Comment: I see it too. This captcha can not been loaded from google. There is a redirect to another page that is not matches with requested captcha image. You can try to repeat an address request using another exit node.

Comment: I am also trying to figure things out. I only have this problem when I am on a certain internet provider. I switched to another and the CAPTCHA worked. My problem is if I am human, how do I pass the test when the CAPTCHA doesn't show up?

Comment: I think that you see a connect there where it is not present. There is no difference between what provider you are using to enter into network, because your site has been requested from exit node.

Comment: Decreasing value of circuit timeout changing also can help (your nodes switches more often and as a result there is more chances that your exit node is not blocked to request captcha image).

Comment: _"I only have this problem when I am on a certain internet provider. I switched to another and the CAPTCHA worked."_ <-- Holy sh!t. If that was not coincidence, then cloudflare or the captcha provider (or both?) can distinguish which ISP you use.

Comment: I never had the same problem like OP. But with Cloudfare there are problems: You have to activate JavaScripts, without the entered Captachas don't work. With JS activated, you are less anonym. Is there another way to pass Cloudfare?

Comment: Same problem with Firefox on Tor. Just started.
However tried Pirate Browser instead and captcha shows.
I have no idea why but it is a way round for now.

Comment: @Jobiwan cloudflare only blocks certain exit nodes (possibly also only some of the time). Switching ISP's most likely means using a different exit node as well since you'd be reconnecting (similar to hitting "new identity") and there'd be some time lag. Sh!t has not yet achieved holiness.

Comment: Allow Java scripts on the page and then click the check button.

Answer (score 1):

I'd noticed some time ago that in Cloudflare captchas, the scripts seem to be all-or-nothing. I can solve them with javascript completely disallowed, but having only some allowed results in the anomaly. Here is a test case:

[image]

The box to type the solved strings into isn't present, as you can see.

Just to complicate things, if I solve with zero scripts allowed and get to the site's page, then erase the site's cookies and reload the page, I can get a different problem in the subsequent captcha. Lots of combinations are possible. Oh what a tangled web they weave.

[image]